# StreamReader.ReadLine returns NULL string C#

Tags: c#, string, csv, streamreader, readline

I'm trying to read a `.CSV` file line by line, each line contains:

```
name, age, occupation, ID
```

My `.csv` file has 3 lines currently and when I try to read them, I always get a null value for my string.

Here is the code:

```
public static List<Person> ReadFileToList(string filePath)
{
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
    string personstring;

    while ((personstring = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Person person = ConvertStringToPerson(personstring);
        personList.Add(person);
    }

    return personList;       
}

private static Person ConvertStringToPerson(string personString)
{
    string[] personData = personString.Split(',');

    if (personData.Length == 4)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Parse(personData[3]);
        return new Person(personData[0], personData[1], personData[2], id);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FormatException(personString + "is an incorrect format");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ops my bad, it is C#

Comment: Use window explorer to check size of file.  It is probably zero bytes long.

Comment: Just did. Size: 169 bytes, Size on Disk: 0 bytes

Comment: remove the second `personstring = reader.ReadLine();`, it's already reading the line in `while ((personstring = reader.ReadLine()) != null)`. Easier with `File.ReadLines` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503#Examples

Comment: I tried it with File.ReadLines and a foreach loop and got the same result, the string is always null

Comment: That second reader.ReadLine(); could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code reads two lines from the stream for each line it actually parses:

```
while ((personstring = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    personstring = reader.ReadLine();
```

Get rid of the 2nd `ReadLine()` call.

While I'm here, `.Split(',')` is **NOT** a good way to parse CSV data. There are many good dedicated CSV parsers out there on NuGet, and (at least) three already built into the .Net framework. Use one of those.

Comment: his problem was "after each line there is an empty line in the file", and thinking that `""` is null

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a line, storing it into `personString`, testing it for null, then throwing it away and reading *another* line into `personString`. So if the first read returned the last line, the next one will return null. You are throwing away all the odd-numbered lines.

Get rid of the `ReadLine()` inside the loop:

```
while ((personstring = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Person person = ConvertStringToPerson(personstring);
    personList.Add(person);
}
```

You can see by inspection that it is now impossible for `personstring` to be null inside the loop. However by the same argument it *will* be null *after* the loop.

Comment: I removed the "personstring = reader.ReadLine();" inside the while loop, (i tried out so many different versions already that i accidently put it in there twice). The result is the same tho, the string i get is still null

Comment: The string you get cannot now be null inside the loop. Buf it the file is zero length as you state in comments, it will be null *after* the loop.

Comment: The file has 169 bytes, the file has 3 lines in it, i checked it multiple times.

Comment: But you wrote 'Size on Disk: 0 bytes'.

Comment: I googled it and it apparently shows 0 bytes for small files that take up less than 1KB space on the disk, but the size of the file is 169 Bytes.

Comment: OK. But `personString` cannot possibly be null inside the corrected read loop, by inspection. Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: The code of my program is not very long and I dont really know where the issue could be, i'm checking it with the debugger and it shows me the error is always here.

Comment: You haven't shown any error here. You've only asserted that it is null at some unstated point. It *will* be null *after* the loop, because that's how the loop terminates.

Comment: But the problem is that it is null inside the loop. My method "ConvertStringToPerson" runs once in every iteration of the while loop but it gets the value null for personString and thats why it cannot convert it.

Comment: Then this isn't the real code, or you haven't applied this fix. With the loop *as I posted it above,* what you claim is self-evidently impossibe.

Comment: @WatchesaFriendVideos Not believing you.

Comment: I copy pasted your code but i unfortnately still get null for the string, i know the code should work so the error might be somewhere else but i cannot figure out where

Comment: You get null for *what* string? It is not possible for `personstring` to be null inside that loop. What is your evidence? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: my problem was that i could not split the personString in a array with the length of 4, although it should be possible but i only got an personString with the value "" when i checked with debugger

Comment: `""` isn't a null, it is an empty string, and being able to split the string *at all* is *prima facie* evidence that it *wasn't* null. Really this is ridiculous. Very poor quality thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the last line of the file is empty. You can try checking for that:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)) 
    {
        Person person = ConvertStringToPerson(line);
        personList.Add(person);
    }
}
```

---

Shorter alternative `using System.Linq` :

```
List<Person> personList = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))
    .Select(ConvertStringToPerson).ToList();
```

Comment: An empty line won't be read as a null.

Comment: This worked for me thanks, after each line there is an empty line in the file, but thats probably my fault in the WriteFile class :)  EDIT: this only shows in Excel, in notepad its perfectly fine

Comment: @WatchesaFriendVideos So it wasn't null at all, it was empty, or had fewer than 4 columns.

Comment: when i checked the string with debugger it said personString = "" and when i used personString.Split(',') it returned me an array with the length of 1

Comment: Exactly as I said. `""` is a zero length string, not a null one, and if it had been null, `personString.split()` would have failed instead of returning a result. So it wasn't null. So your entire question was a complete waste of everybody's time. I don't care about yours, but mine is valuable.

Comment: Im very sorry, i assumed the "" was null.